# The program suddenly stops somewhy. How could I solve this?

Tags: java, freeze

I've made a game (snake), and it's working well.
But when I collect 69 (+-10) coins/food, everything stops/freezes, and I can't close the window, without task manager (because it's not answering).

After I close the window, the netbeans throw an error message (1st row):

```
Java Result: -805306369
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 minutes 26 seconds)
```

And that's all...

I use "int" everywhere in the code, and I use "Timer", to move everithing.
(The code is quite long, and there is 5 ".java" file)

As I know, this is an exit code maybe because the corrupted workspace, but changing directory is not helping.

I start the program from Netbeans.

What's the reason of the freezing?